# How to switch data in a column and update the column with result information in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `USERS` and it has a column `FULLNAME` that contains full users names in the format `FirstName LastName` and I need to switch the data, and update it in the same column, using this format `LastName, FirstName`.

Ex. `James Brown` needs to be switched to `Brown, James` and updated in the same column (`FULLNAME`)

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You really should have two columns: `FirstName` and `LastName` and _possibly_ a computed column for `FullName`.

Comment: This is a really tricky problem. What happens when you have names like `De Wayne Buice` or `Kiki Van Der Wall`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they only have 1 space in the name:

```
UPDATE USERS
SET FULLNAME = RIGHT(FULLNAME,len(FULLNAME) - CHARINDEX(' ',FULLNAME)) +', '+ LEFT(FULLNAME,charindex(' ',FULLNAME)-1)
WHERE LEN(FULLNAME) - LEN(REPLACE(FULLNAME, ' ', '')) = 1
```

Comment: This is a very simplistic view of the problem. If you see the example, the name was "James Brown", and op wants "Brown, James", s/he actually needs to identify one part as a last name and another as a first name. S/he needs a names dictionary as a minimum to solve this.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The question seems to imply he knows the part before the space is the first name.

Comment: You may be right, I was thinking of a broader solution, but it seems that it fits for the current question

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
This script fixed it.
UPDATE yourTable 
    Set name = RIGHT(name,len(name) - CHARINDEX(' ',name)) +', '+ LEFT(name,charindex(' ',name)) 
    WHERE LEN(name) - LEN(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) = 1

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to split the elements into two columns (LastName, FirstName).  However, if you want to try and squeeze it into 1 column, and you're assuming that every name is split by a single space

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE ( Name VARCHAR(100) )

    INSERT  INTO @Users
            ( Name 
            )
            SELECT  'James Brown'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  'Mary Ann Watson'


    SELECT  RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) + ', ' + LEFT(Name,
                                                                  LEN(Name)
                                                                  - CHARINDEX(' ',
                                                                  REVERSE(Name)))
    FROM    @Users
```

This also assumes that if they have more than two names sperated by a space, then the last word is the last name, and everything else is first name.  Works for "Mary Ann Watson", but not "George Tucker Jones", if "Tucker Jones" is a last name.